# OOP validation PHP

Tags: php, oop

Currently I'm trying to validate an email address via OOP php with arrays so I can add additional functions later, however when I insert a valid email address the validation still fails, I think perhaps my arrays are set up wrong but I'm not entirely sure, additionally I had tried different different operators to check if the email function would output different results however as mentioned it always seems to fail, any advice would be appreciated

```
class Login
{   
    private 
    $email,
    $password,
    $database,
    $db = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database;
    }

    public function validEmail($email)
    {   
        return (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== FALSE);  
    }   
}






      <?php 
require "classes/Login.class.php";
$validate = new Login();

        require "loadclasses.php";

            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
            {
                $email = $pass = "";
                $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);     

                $email = $post['email-login'];
                $pass = $post['password-login'];        
                $errors = array();


                $fields = array(
                 'email-login' => array(        
                     'validate' => 'validEmail',
                     'message'   => 'Enter a valid email address'
                    )
                );


                foreach($fields as $key => $value) 
                {
                    if(isset($fields[$key])) 
                    {
                        $errors[] = ['name' => $key, 'error' => $fields[$key]['message']];
                    }
                }



                if(empty($errors)) 
                {
                     $success = ['response' => 'true']; 
                     session_start();
                }   

            }



        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        if (empty($errors))
        {
            echo json_encode($success);
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode(["errors" => $errors]);
        }
```

Comment: You are not using your Login class anywhere. This doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments - you don't use functions from your `Login` class.

So, how you current code works:

```
$fields = array(
  'email-login' => array(        
     'validate' => 'validEmail',
     'message'   => 'Enter a valid email address'
  )
);

foreach($fields as $key => $value) 
{
    // isset($fields[$key]) is ALWAYS true
    if(isset($fields[$key])) 
    {
        $errors[] = ['name' => $key, 'error' => $fields[$key]['message']];
    }
}
```

What you really should do is something like:

```
$fields = array(
  'email-login' => array(        
     'validate' => 'validEmail',
     'message'   => 'Enter a valid email address'
  )
);
// instantiate object of Login class
$login = new Login();

foreach($fields as $key => $value) 
{
    // call a function `$value['validate']` (it is `validEmail`)
    $validation_result = $login->{$value['validate']}($email);

    // if validation fails - add error message
    if(!$validation_result) 
    {
        $errors[] = ['name' => $key, 'error' => $value['message']];
    }
}
```

And btw `$post` is a wrong variable name, I suppose it is `$_POST`.

Comment: Ah I can see my mistake now, thank you.  Yes you're right I had accidentally deleted two lines of code when I was copying it over, rather silly of me